# C# lambda expression and capturing outer variables

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to understand why, in the following example, the value of 'fac' is the value 2, even after there's an assignment to the value 3.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int fac = 1;

        Func<int, int> mul = (n) =>
        {
            fac = 2;
            return fac * fac;
        };

        fac = 3;

        Console.WriteLine(mul(fac));
        Console.WriteLine(fac);
    }
}
```

**result:**

4

2

I know that lambda expressions can themselves update captured variables (in this case 'fac') but to this extent seems confusing.

Comment: the lambda expression is invoked after setting the value to 3. so last assignment would be 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...the value of 'fac' is the value 2, even after there's an assignment to the value 3.

This statement is not the whole story.

First, `fac` is assigned to 1. Next, `fac` is assigned to 3. When you call `mul()`, `fac` is assigned to 2.

In all cases, the same variable `fac` is modified, and the assignment inside `mul()` doesn't occur until `mul()` is called.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I forgot that captured variables are evaluated when the delegate is invoked, not when captured.